# Cron does literally nothing

Tags: cron

I'm currently trying to get the cron daemon to work, but it won't execute anything. The crontab file currently contains this text:

`'* * * * * echo "hello"'`

Which should print a `hello` message every minute.

However, this command is never carried out. I've tried everything, restarting cron, reinstalling cron, creating a root crontab, checking whether cron was running in the first place, but nothing gives any results. Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to not be working because you aren't sending the echo anywhere, so it looks like it is failing. You need to send it to a terminal, like `pts/1` or something.

To find out a terminal you can send it to, type in `w` at a command prompt.  You should see something like the following:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ w
 16:00:43 up 1 day, 22:38,  3 users,  load average: 0.89, 0.60, 0.50
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
terrance tty7     :0               Sat17   46:38m  4:15m  7.24s /sbin/upstart -
terrance pts/16   :0.0             Sun10    7:30m  0.07s  7.78s /usr/bin/xfce4-
terrance pts/1    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   16:00    2.00s  0.06s  0.00s w
```

There you see my last command of `w` appeared on `pts/1`.  So, for your crontab keeping that terminal open, have your line read

```
* * * * * echo "hello" > /dev/pts/1
```

Then in about 1 minute you should see `hello` appear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked, I'm stupid.

Comment: @111111 Not stupid.  Sometimes it takes a second pair eyes to help.  Glad I could help you out!  =)